# my imports are underlined in red even though they work in Eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In pydev I have a python package called webcrawler.  This package is in the directory '/home/raido/Workspace/WebCrawler'  The package contains a number of modules; website, tier, referrer, etc. etc...  Each module contains a series of functions.  I wanted to use one of these functions in another pydev project so I typed....

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/raido/Workspace/WebCrawler')
from webcrawler import website

print website.getXmlLang('http://www.google.com')
```

The script runs fine and runs the function that prints out the information.  What I don't understand is why the word website in the "from webcrawler import website" line is underlined in red.  The error says...

```
Unresolved import: website
website Found at: TestUrl

from webcrawler import website
```

However, everything appears to run fine.  Is this a pydev bug?  How do I fix this?  I tried doing it this way.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/raido/Workspace/WebCrawler')
from webcrawler.website import getXmlLang

print getXmlLang('http://www.google.com')
```

Even though this also works doing it this way also underlines the import "getXmlLang" in red.

Python 2.6.5
Eclipse 3.7.1
PyDev 2.5.0.2012050419
Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: is the folder WebCrawler your actual package? or you have another package called webcrawler (lowercase) inside that folder? does it contain an _ _init_ _.py file? if the package is WebCrawler try renaming it to lowercase only..

Comment: The WebCrawler folder (uppercase) is the project folder that Eclipse created, it is not my package.  The package, webcrawler (lowercase) is in the WebCrawler folder.  Inside of webcrawler is an __init__.py file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add all libraries used by your project in *PyDev - PYTHONPATH/External Libraries* tab which you can find in project's properties. This should solve the problem.